# Kafka offset is reset after restart

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-flink, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Apache Kafka 2.11-0 and deploy into container in GKE.
I put 3 replicas for the HA and the message is consumed by Flink Job.

I'm using persistent volume in /var/lib/kafka 
and this is my base docker image: kubernetes-kafka/kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1

I have 1 topic using 4 partitions 
I notice that once there's 1 kafka node is restarted, the offset is reset to 0.
I didn't overwrite the value of auto.offset.reset , which default should be latest.

Is there any reasons why the offset is reset ?

Comment: `2.11` is not a Kafka version... Are you not using persistent volumes in your GKE installation? What's the replication factor of your kafka topic?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Im using persist volume in  /var/lib/kafka. I'm using this in my kafka.yaml apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  selector:
   matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  replicas: 3
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] your question to include these details. Also, I wasn't asking about k8s service replicas. I was asking about the Kafka topic replication factor

Comment: Also, what docker image are you using for your brokers?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, how to check that? I set 1 topic into 4 partitions, other config mostly using default. This is my docker image kubernetes-kafka/kubernetes-kafka:1.0-10.2.1

Comment: I try running this command : kafka@kafka-0:/$ kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk:2181 --topic Customer  \

2022-09-23 11:14:27  Topic:Customer PartitionCount:4 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:retention.ms=432000000,retention.bytes=24159191040
2022-09-23 11:14:27   Topic: Customer Partition: 0 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
2022-09-23 11:14:27   Topic: Customer Partition: 1 Leader: 2 Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
2022-09-23 11:14:27   Topic: Customer Partition: 2 Leader: 0 Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
2022-09-23 11:14:27   Topic: Customer Partition: 3 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1

Comment: I suggest not using such an old version of Kafka. If you want to use Kubernetes, refer https://strimzi.io or search Bitnami/Confluent in GCP marketplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your topic only has one ReplicationFactor, so if Broker ID=1 goes down, then it's data will all be unavailable.

If you want to persist that topic data, increasing its replication factor is a good idea, but also sounds like your persistent volumes aren't working as expected

You'll also want to double check your `offsets.topic.replication.factor` value to ensure it's also not set to 1, otherwise, your consumers such as Flink will get reset when the broker hosting that topic loses its data.